# How to input batch variable information into a website?

Tags: batch-file, text, web

I am working on a decoder, and as of now, I have the main part. I was wondering if you could set a variable in batch (via set /p) and put that variable into a website's input box. Then how would I continue to decode.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set /P Input=[Enter Input Here]

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%a in ("%input%") do (
set bit=%%a
set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%c in ('cmd /D /U /C echo %%b^| find /V ""') do (
  for /L %%i in (1,1,%%c) do set "output=!output!!bit!"
  set /A "bit=^!bit"
)
)
echo %output%
```

How would I put output into the "binary to decode" section and put click the "to text" button from batch, then echo the txt output from the website. If this includes vb or vbs, you would have to include the program for me. I don't know any vb/vbs. Here is the site: http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_to_Text.asp

Comment: Not happening in batch mate.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in vbs or vb?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you even asking this question? It isn't possible.  I know everything in batch and HTML. If you want to do that, you can do it in PHP.